# Generating Print Version of PDF with specified DPI in Reportlab

Tags: python, linux, django, reportlab

I am writing a program to generate PDF files using Python's [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) library. Basically I have two requirements:

1. Web version: RGB color, 150 dpi
2. Print Version: CMYK color, 300 dpi

So far I have generated the pdf and set Color to CMYK / RGB. But I have not been able to change the DPI of the pdf file. Does reportlab provide any function to set dpi to specified.

Furthermore, any program that can run on Linux terminal to convert DPI after a pdf is generated can also be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDF's by spec have no native DPI - it's mostly all vector based (what is not vectored is often what you put in there as rasterized).  AKA images you embedded will be rasterized (unless your image is vector/svg).  The pdf renderer on the other-hand does have 'dpi' settings.  For instance, you can change the default 'dpi' (or pt-pi/points per inch) in adobe reader (most renderers I have seen support this).

[image: Change Adobe Reader settings]

If you want 300+ 'dpi' for print, and you have all vector based content, don't worry about it - the print shop just adjusts the dpi on their end and 'bam!' instant 300+ dpi (in theory they can select an infinitely high rendering dpi - the glory of vector based tech).

If you have images that are rasterized, then you'll want to do some up-front math to convert dpi to points, where points relate to real-world measurements regardless of the media you are look at.  To make things easier, it's 1:1 relationship (see [here](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-reference.pdf), drawImage())In general, if you want 300dpi at the printer, and you have an image that you know you want to stretch 300 points, and your image currently is set to 600 dpi then you know you need to embed the image at 1/2 the dimensions of it's current size (which can be controlled by drawImage() where it accepts width/height kwargs).  Alternatively, if you have a smaller image and try to up-scale the dimensions, it'll be like drawing on the surface of a balloon and then inflating it - it'll be stretched/distorted in ways that you won't want (aka better to start large and scale down).

(source [PostScript Reference](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf) p. 12)

> The resolution of a raster output device is a measure of the number of
>   pixels per unit of distance along the two linear dimensions.
>   Resolution is typically—but not necessarily—the same horizontally and
>   vertically.  Manufacturers’ decisions on device technology and
>   price/performance tradeoffs create characteristic ranges of
>   resolution:
>
> • Computer displays have relatively low resolution,
>   typically 75 to 110 pixels per inch.
>   • Dot-matrix printers generally
>   range from 100 to 250 pixels per inch.
>   • Ink-jet and laser-scanned
>   xerographic printing technologies are capable of medium-resolution
>   output of 300 to 1400 pixels per inch.
>   • Photographic technology permits high resolutions of 2400 pixels per inch or more.
>
> Higher resolution yields better quality and ﬁdelity of the resulting output,
>   but is achieved at greater cost. As the technology improves and
>   computing costs decrease, products evolve to higher resolutions.

Read this response:  [previous image quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893928/how-can-i-improve-reportlab-image-quality)

And here is an OLD thread on the topic as well:  [previous thread on reportlab listserv](http://two.pairlist.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2006-January/004670.html)

HTH